# Getting automatically inlogged to the anonymous site

Tags: 2010, anonymous-authentication

I have a SharePoint server 2010 development machine where I have extended the web application so the site can be accessed anonymously to do my tests. Now let's say that i go into http://contoso.private.com:80 and check out one of my pages, then I go into the extended url http://contoso.public.com:80 and browse the page that i just checked out, normally I should get error as the page is unpublished but in my case i get automatically logged in to the page so I can see it although it's checked-out from inside. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may be similar to an issue I've had before.  Does your anonymous url happen to be a sub-domain of the non-anonymous url?  If so, I bet domain cookie sharing could be the culprit.  When you sign in, SP add a cookie so that it knows you have already authenticated correctly. If the anonymous URL is a subdomain of the non-anonymous url, then when viewing the anonymous URL, your browser will send back the cookie of the non-anonymous url because the non-anonymous url is a higher level domain.

For more details on my specific problem and the cookies uses, see my blog post here:  http://steve.thelineberrys.com/sharepoint-dns-name-considerations-when-using-anonymous-access-2/

Comment: Steve, I really appreciate your fast reply. After doing some tests and comparing my development machine to the acceptance environment I found a little difference between them, specifically in the Authentication Providers when extending a web application, i had checked in Enable anonymous access on both Default zone and Internet zone, i changed it so that only the Internet zone have this box in-checked and it was solved. Worth to mention is that it took a bit of time before i noticed that it was fixed.

Comment: Good, i'm glad you were able to get it working.